# Securing WCF Data Service with SSL and forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

[image]

I have an issue with authenticating a WCF Data Service with forms authentication and ssl. I call `Membership.ValidateUser` to authenticate, then I complete with the data service.

The problem is: I looked at the data in Fiddler, and I see that I still manage to see the user name and password in the request header.

I looked at the `ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider` code, and I see it sends the username and password in the body of the request . So why I can see it in the request message?

Please see in the image my situation.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: The image is soooo small - it's unusable

Comment: In your web browser, right-click the tiny image and 'show image' to bring the image up in its own window. The actual image is much larger, just scaled down in SO. It is actually readable if you bring it up in its own window :)   Also, @Wasim -  do you have Fiddler set up to decrypt SSL traffic? If so, it might just be showing you the decrypted SSL, hence you see it plain text? Just guessing...

Comment: Thanks , I have fiddler . There is a smart client talks with service . Any one put fiddler can see any sensitive data the client sends . Btw, the ssl certificate it self signed one yet .